# Calling a method from an argument

Tags: java

I apologize if this is a duplicate question, I want to be able to call a method that is defined in the constructors argument list from a different method.

What follows is code that won't compile, but its really the only way I can think of describing my question. I also hope my explanation makes sense.

Main.java

```
....
Class0 instance = new Class0(arg0, arg1, arg2, new Class1(){
        //do something
        //do something else
        //do more stuff
    }
)
library.go(instance);
....
```

The point I want to get across here is that a new instance of Class0 is initialized with an anonymous function. 
The instance is then passed to an instance of Library.

Class0.java

```
....
public Class1 action = null;
public Class0(int arg0, int arg1, int arg2, Class1 class) {
     setArg0(arg0);
     setArg1(arg1);
     setArg2(arg2);
     setAction(class);
}
public setAction(Class1 class) {
     action = class;
}
public action() {
     class;
}
....
```

Class0 is constructed from the constructor method and sets the function to the action field, it remains uncalled but stored for later. 
action() calls the function passed into the constructor.

Library.java

```
....
public void go(Class0 class0) {
    class0.action();
}
....
```

For the most part Library.java is out of my control, it is an conduit for a third-party library.
go calls the stored function of the instance object, declared in main, through its action method.

Does anything like this even remotely exist in java? Is there any other way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: first reason it won't compile is you shouldn't use reserved key word like `class` as var name. then `action` should have return value.

Comment: Use lambdas or interfaces declaring the required methods.

Comment: Read up on the new lambda functionality in Java 8

Comment: I'm trying to keep compatibility down to java 6, i will look into interfaces for now,

Comment: "I apologize if this is a duplicate question" - Downvoting because you didn't show any research effort.

Comment: If I googled callbacks i probably would have found something. I had literally no idea what to search for. Thanks for letting me know why you down voted at least.

Comment: That's not an "anonymous function", it's an anonymous inner class. It isn't really clear what your asking. You never show us the definition of Class1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:  This assumes java 7.0 or earlier.  It works in java 8, but lambda expressions are most likely preferred.

It appears that you want to implement a callback interface.

1. create an interface with a method.
2. use the interface as a parameter to a method (constructor in your case).
3. the interface is just a reference to some object, so call the method.

Here is some code:

Kapow.java

```
public interface Kapow
{
    void callbackMethod();
}
```

KapowImpl.java

```
public class KapowImpl implements Kapow
{
    @Override
    public void callbackMethod()
    {
        System.out.println("Kapow!");
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
public final class Main
{
    private static void callIt(final Kapow theCallback)
    {
        theCallback.callbackMethod();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Kapow kapowObject = new KapowImpl();

        callIt(kapowObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: For clarity, this means that for each different callback i wish to use i'm require to create separate classes for the implementations? I can't do it anonymously?

Comment: That's right. But if possible, you should reuse `@FunctionalInterface`s (so called in Java 8 with lambda expressions introduced). http://java.dzone.com/articles/introduction-functional-1

Answer (score 0):

A good example of a "method type declaration" is `java.awt.event.ActionListener` (see below). In Java 8 or higher you can use use [lambda expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) to simplify the usage, but the principle is still the same - an interface with one method declaration stands for the logical method.

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 1996, 2006, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
 * ORACLE PROPRIETARY/CONFIDENTIAL. Use is subject to license terms.
 */

package java.awt.event;

import java.util.EventListener;

/**
 * The listener interface for receiving action events.
 * The class that is interested in processing an action event
 * implements this interface, and the object created with that
 * class is registered with a component, using the component's
 * <code>addActionListener</code> method. When the action event
 * occurs, that object's <code>actionPerformed</code> method is
 * invoked.
 *
 * @see ActionEvent
 * @see <a href="http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/post1.0/ui/eventmodel.html">Tutorial: Java 1.1 Event Model</a>
 *
 * @author Carl Quinn
 * @since 1.1
 */
public interface ActionListener extends EventListener {

    /**
     * Invoked when an action occurs.
     */
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e);

}
```

Here's a quick example on how to use that pattern:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ActionListener squeezeAction = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Ouch!");
        }
    };
    performAction(squeezeAction);
}

public static void performAction(ActionListener method) {
    method.actionPerformed(null); //invoke method
}
```

With lambda expressions (requires JRE 1.8 or higher) this can be simplified to:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ActionListener squeezeAction = e -> System.out.println("Ouch!");
    performAction(squeezeAction);
}

public static void performAction(ActionListener method) {
    method.actionPerformed(null); //invoke method
}
```

Or as a reference to an existing method:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ActionListener squeezeAction = Test::squeeze;
        performAction(squeezeAction);
    }

    public static void sqeeze(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Ouch!");
    }

    public static void performAction(ActionListener method) {
        method.actionPerformed(null); //invoke method
    }
}
```