# Putting all fileds in the same Object?

Tags: java, class

I have the following class hierarchy:

```
public enum Bonus{
    FP,
    PRECOIL,
    //some ohter types
};

public interface Generator{

    public Object generate();

};


public class DateGenerator implements Generator{

   public String queryString;

   public Integer order;

   //GET, SET

   public Date generate(){
       //implementation
   }
};

public class BonusEnumGenerator implements Generator{

   public Date bonusAppliedDate;

   public String description;

   //GET, SET

   public Bonus generate(){
       //implementation
   }
}
```

So I need to put those params for generating the objects into a generalized Object.

Is it considered good if I create the class, say `GeneratorParams` and put all the params for all `Generator`'s implementations. In my particular case I would have:

```
public class GeneratorParams{

    public String queryString;

    public Integer order;

    public Date bonusAppliedDate;

    public String description;
}
```

What's annoying me is that I put params which don't relate to each other in the same object. Is it good?

***Why do I want to put all the params into a single object?***

Beucase I want to write more generalized code. In that case I would have:

```
public interface Generator{

    public Object generate();

    public void applyParams(GeneratorParams params);

};
```

and `applyParams` method would be implemented for each type of `Generator`.

So I could write something like this:

```
Generator g = GeneratorPrototypeFactory.createGenerator(TypeId typeId);
GeneratorParams p;
//Getting params
g.applyParams(p);
Object generated = g.generate();
```

How can I solve that in more appropriate way?

Comment: No, it's not good. Can you explain further why you need to put all the params into a generalized object? What is the use case?

Comment: The parameters are common to all the implementations and you don't want to declare all of them each time or why would you need to have them in a single class?

Comment: It sounds loosely if you are talking about the Facade pattern.

Comment: A short answer would have been "no, you don't have to put all parameters in a generalized object". I'm still curious about why you need to do this.

Comment: @E_net4 Could you look at the question one more time? I've updated it.

Comment: I see. Perhaps a bundle-like structure is what you're looking for.

Comment: @E_net4 Waht's that? Maybe you can provide an example?

Comment: Why don't you have an abstract class named `generator` instead of the interface and put the parameters in the abstract class?

Comment: @Blip Because the parameters are different for each subclass.

Comment: How do you propose to decide each time which object you want to generate and which parameters to apply to the generator?

Comment: @RealSkeptic That's the Factory's matter. Of course, I'll provide some type identifier as the argument for the factory method.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I've fixed that.

Comment: What is the need for this method `public void applyParams(GeneratorParams params)`?

Comment: So basically, you are telling the factory that you want an object such-and-such type, and then you create parameters that go with same type, and then you generate. Right? So why isn't your `GeneratorParams` itself an interface?

Comment: @Blip I thought it should be clear from the method's name. It is to apply params encapsulated within `params` object.

Comment: @RealSkeptic How could it be an interface? I should store values into it. What would be the implementation then?

Comment: A specific object, implementing it, that has parameters that are correct for the type of object you want to generate.

Comment: By the `applyParams` approach, objects of `GeneratorParams` must be generic enough to support any possible combination of generator parameters. Something like a map to parameters could be used.

Comment: @E_net4 For example...? If we add new implementation of Generator we just add new field into GeneratorParams. What's wrong with that?

Comment: If i understand you correctly, the way I have achieved this is by using callbacks triggered by a generic super class. This way everything can be unique to the specific type of class, and you are able to call a specific method through a generic class.

Comment: @user3663882 It's that 10 generators with 10 different parameters will result in an object with 100 fields. ;) In short, it doesn't scale well unless you make a generic bundle.

Comment: @E_net4 Now I see the problem and completely agree with you. I don't understand how to create such a bundle. Maybe you can provide that as an answer?

Comment: @doveyg Maybe you're right, but it's not clear to me without an example. Please provide some, if you can.

Comment: @user3663882, Certainly [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29035961/calling-a-method-from-an-argument)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply make `GeneratorParams` an abstract class and move any common (in `Date` and `BonusEnum` generator) parameter to that:

```
public abstract class GeneratorParams {

    public String commonParam;
    //GET, SET
}
```

then add two sub-class:

```
public class DateGeneratorParams extends GeneratorParams {

    public String queryString;
    public Integer order;   
    //    GET, SET
}

public class BonusEnumGeneratorParams implements GeneratorParams {

    public Date bonusAppliedDate;
    public String description;    
    //    GET, SET 
}
```

now implement appropriate `applyParam` in `DateGenerator` and `BonusEnumGenerator`:

```
public class DateGenerator implements Generator {    
    public String queryString;
    public Integer order;    
    //GET, SET

    public Date generate(){
        //implementation
    }

    @Override
    public void applyParams(GeneratorParams params) throws InvalidParamException {
        if(!(params instanceof DateGeneratorParams))
            throw new InvalidParamException();
        else
        // assign values
    }    
}
```

and

```
public class BonusEnumGenerator implements Generator {

    public Date bonusAppliedDate;
    public String description;    
    //GET, SET

    public Bonus generate() {
        //implementation
    }

    public void applyParams(GeneratorParams params) throws InvalidParamException {
        if(!(params instanceof BonusEnumGeneratorParams))
            throw new InvalidParamException();
        else
            // assign values
    }    
}
```

Comment: But I don't have common params ever.

Comment: I said if you have add it. if you don't have any remove `commonParam`.

Comment: Well, it will an empty class then. Is it useful to create such classes?

Comment: when your project grows you may found common parameter and this class is the best place to put them. if you exactily know that there is no common parameter make `GeneratorParams` an interface. and an empty interface may be useful for generalizing code...

Comment: Hah, the solution was pretty simpe, actually. Thank you.